# Проблема установки пакета gulp-sass

Tags: gulp, gulp-sass

[image: список ошибок]Я начал устанавливать пакеты для gulp. Gulp установился без проблем, начал устанавливать gulp-sass, появились ошибки которые я не знаю как решить. Я вижу, что проблема как то связана с build tools, но не знаю как ее решить.

Comment: где-то там на картинке вам рекомендуют обновить ваш node-gyp 3-тьей версии (при 7мой-то актуальной)

Comment: попробовал обновить node-gyp, не получилось, выдаёт те же ошибки